# Adding GA4 using tag manager causes performance issue

Tags: seo, google-analytics, performance, google-tag-manager

I have added GA4 (google analytics 4) using GTM (google tag manager) and the google PageSpeedInsight complains about it and I get failed in Core Web Vitals Assessment:

[image]

And here is how it complains:

[image]

Any idea how can I fix it? Have I configured GTM wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it causing any real performance issues? The reduce unused JavaScript is just a hint at what may be a performance issue. It's quite dumb as it does not know if that JavaScript is used when users interact with the page or on other pages where it is added. And it does not identify if it is causing delays in anything.

Your Core Web Vitals is failing because of TTFB which means your server is slow at returning the initial HTML. I'd focus on that.

Comment: The Core Web Vitals fails exactly because of the LCP https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajtgA.png

Comment: @MartinAJ Your unused JS totals 0.6s for transfer, whereas your TTFB is 1.6s (which itself contributes to the LCP time).

Comment: Oh, right .. thx